# How to create a portal/modal in Next 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog, react-portal

I wanted to create a Modal in NextJS 13.4 (with the new layout.tsx file system), But I couldn't. since this is a new thing I couldn't find a solution on the web either.

Here are the things that I've tried:

**Edit**:

1. In the solutions:

```
import React from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

const Modal = () => {
    return createPortal(
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>your content</div>
        </React.Fragment>,
        Document.body as HTMLElement
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

It will throw:

> document is not defined

Tried to import Document from 'next/document' but still not working.

Another Error was `error Error: createPortal was called on the server. Portals are not currently supported on the server. Update your program to conditionally call createPortal on the client only.`

I've added "use client" on the first line and it will solve that error.

But still no results in showing that modal content.

2. [How to create a portal in Next Js](https://www.learnbestcoding.com/post/101/how-to-create-a-portal-in-next-js)

Since the step 1 of this tutorial is telling to create a _document file and place your portal element with a specific ID there, I did this in Layout.tsx (I think its the same as document file).

[image: layout.tsx codes]

Resulted in: **Hydration Error**

3. Other tutorials also resulted the same...

Please provide a valid answer. I know how to create a portal in react or previous versions of next. This is a new version that has been changed insignificantly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make your `Modal` component compatible with Next.js 13 app router in two easy steps:

1. Declare your `Modal` as a client component by adding the `"use client"` annotation
2. Render its children only when the component has mounted on the client.

```
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

export default function Modal({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => setMounted(true), []);

  return mounted ? createPortal(<>{children}</>, document.body) : null;
}
```

Comment: I was previously using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-portal to do this because I didn't know about createPortal. But after I upgraded to next 13.5 react-portal stopped working. Found this answer and replaced it with react-portal now everything started working again.

Comment: Keep in mind that while this solution is recommended in 99% of cases, it can lead to a reduction in the CLS score in certain scenarios. For instance, if you're aiming to immediately display a banner on a page and this solution delays the banner until after the page has loaded, it may cause the page content to shift downwards.

Answer (score 3):

When using the above code by Igor, in case it's not clear, your content goes here: <>{children}</>.

For Example:

```
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

export default function Modal() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => setMounted(true), []);

  return mounted ? createPortal(<div>your content</div>, document.body) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is cool for a simple app, but how do you do when you have Providers / Navbar / Footer already nested in the body element? Here's an example as I can't manage to make it work properly, it keeps being generated outside of the body element:

```
  export default function RootLayout({ children }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={playfairDisplay.className}>
        <Providers>
          <PolyNav />
          <div id="content-container" style={{ marginTop: "5.5rem" }}>
            {children}
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrap my layout.tsx this way:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Providers>
          <ReduxProviders>
            <div id='portal'>
              <NavBar/>
              <Sidebar/>
              {children}
            </div>
          </ReduxProviders>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

And my component looks like this:

```
export default function NotesPage() {

    const [ modalOpen, setModalOpen ] = useState(false)
    const [portalElement, setPortalElement] = useState<Element | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setPortalElement(document.getElementById("portal"));
    }, []);

    const modalHandler = () => {
        setModalOpen(!modalOpen)
    }

    return (
        <main className="flex justify-between min-h-screen mt-20">
            { modalOpen && portalElement 
                ? createPortal( <Modal/>, portalElement ) 
                : null
            }
            <nav className="w-72 border-l-2 order-last mr-48">
                <button onClick={notebookModalHandler}
                >   
                    Open Modal
                </button>
            </nav>
            
        </main>
    )
}
```

And works for me

Answer (score -1):

you can use react-dom create portal

```
    import React from "react";
    import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

export interface ModalProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  
}

const Modal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({ open, onClose }) => {
  

  if (!open) return null;

  return createPortal(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        your content
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>,
    document.body as HTMLElement
  );
};

export default Modal;
```